# Configuration of Role authorization based on controls asp.net

Tags: asp.net, configuration, authorization, roles

Is there any way to configure a section of an aspx/ascx page, like limiting the controls in a page to the user based on roles,something like section level access that can be configured ?? So that if next time a role has been given additional accesses to view a section that was not accessible before, we can just configure the role instead of changing in the code.
Can this be configured ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can through code:

```
Panel.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole(..);
```

OR

```
Panel.Visible = this.User.Identity.IsInRole("..");
```

And then when you add them to the role, the panel becomes visible.  There's nothing built-in to tie a control to a role, and then change it's visibility.  However, it's very easy to do by code.

Comment: thanks for ur reply... Does permission manager/membership/custom authorization attribute help ??

Comment: Through code its much simpler I do agree,but requirements keep changing i.e if a textbox is visible to a role say manager,through code as u said we will use Roles.IsUserInRole(..)to check n make visible true,next time if the requirement changes and requires the textbox to be invisible to the role manager then again we should look into the code find out where its done and change the logic.Maybe this works fine for a fewer number of controls, in an application which has n number of controls I don't think this is a best practice. Is there any way to configure the same,Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's no in-built integration between security and UI controls; if you want that, you'd have to create your own custom textbox or panel to provide it.  Otherwise, you'd have to supply all of the settings through code.  It's actually not hard to create a custom control...